# Graylog cannot look a field as numeric

Tags: grok, graylog

I use Graylog 2.10.0 to collect the logs. I set a Grok pattern to parse my log, and one field is 
`%{NUMBER:consume_time;int}ms`，and it works well, I capture consume_time correctly, but when I try to use "statistics" function, it only show "Total" and "Cardinality", the other fields are marked as "NaN"。

And I also check the document type in ElasticSearch, it shows the type of "consume_time" is "long".

Anyone can tell me why?

Comment: I'd recommend using one of the official support channels for Graylog to address a larger (specialized) audience: https://www.graylog.org/community-support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the `consume_time` field contained non-numeric values before (in older indices) and the time frame you've selected includes those values.

Try cycling indices (System → Indices → Maintenance) and only select a time frame including this new index to verify this guess.

Comment: It's right, I auto delete the index 3 hours ago, and now it works well, and I got all the results.